# Can't read cyrillic symbols in browser URL using Flask python

Tags: python, url, flask, encoding, utf-8

Good afternoon, everyone!

Basically, I have a problem with reading Cyrillic letters while running my programming code in Python using Flask framework.

[What happens in URL Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkr9F.jpg)

"**mamapapa**" has to be in Cyrillic – "**мамапапа**"

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from unidecode import unidecode
from venv import logger

app = Flask(__name__)
names1=""


@app.route('/hashtags/<string:names>', methods=['GET'])


def get_hashtags(names):

    names1 = "#" + 'names'
    np= logger.start(names1)
    return jsonify({'Сегментация хэштегов': unidecode(np)})



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=9876)
```

As you can see, I've already used **unidecode** in order to translate Cyrillic letters into Latin ones in the row `return jsonify({'Сегментация хэштегов': unidecode(np)})`, but that's not what I exactly wanted to do. My main purpose is to get precisely Cyrillic symbols (like **привет** or **США**) when I get the output.

As far as I've read, there's no possibility to use Cyrillic letters in browser URL? Is it truth or is there any possible way to reach my aim and get that Cyrillic output?

Maybe there's something with **'UTF-8'** encoding/decoding?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a loook at the solution in this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835298/loading-url-with-cyrillic-symbols)

Comment: Take look at the solution in this topic [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835298/loading-url-with-cyrillic-symbols)

Answer (score 0):

You are right. URL character are limited: plain latin letters (a-z, lower case and upper case) and *marks*: `-`, `_`, `.`, `~`. Other characters are escaped with `%` followed by two hex digit. [source: [RFC3986 appendix-A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A)]. Some people could uses creatively other characters, that really split path and arguments (e.g. `+`, parenthesis, etc..

Historically URL were designed to be used by machines (`http://www.` is not the most human readable prefix), so such escaping: you can put all bytes, but such bytes are encoded with `%`.

Domains can uses other characters (outside ASCII), but also in this case, it is just an encoding standard (to ascii): DNS and protocols still use ASCII only characters.

Browsers can do the escaping automatically, and you may display the URL unescaped, but the real url is escaped. You should try for your (or your client) uses case, if such automatic escaping works with their mail clients/browsers.

In any case, with HTML you could display the URL differently as the real URL (on links, and you have some control with javascript) on the url to be displayed on URL bar.

Answer (score 0):

Give at a try unquote.
Example:

```
#Python3
from urllib.parse import unquote
string = unquote('УРЛ')

#Python2
import urllib
url='УРЛ'
urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')
```